# How to solve type of equation with three types of derivatives?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I don`t know how to solve this type of equation and is it possible:
$$m=-\dfrac{1}{32}\dfrac{d(p_0p_1)}{dz}(r-z(r-1))^4-\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{dp_0}{dz}(r-z(r-1))^3$$
$r,m=const$. I have tried with separation of variables, but that is not possible here. What should I do?

Additional information:

for $z=0$, $p_0=p_i, p_1=0$

for $z=1$, $p_0=1, p_1=0$

Comment: Apply the differentiation and separate your expressions. It will easily follow up as a standard approach of an ODE

Comment: How do you exactly mean to apply differentiation, when $p_0$ and $p_1$ are unknown variables? It will be again three variables $p_0,p_1,z$?

Comment: You need two equations for two dependent variables. There isn't enough information to solve